# Android how to retrieve previous and last 5 records in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

In Android, I need to know how to **retrieve previous 5 records and last 5 records** of current index in mysql?

I know only how to retrieve **previous 5 records or last 5 records of current index**.

get previous 5 records of current index

```
Select * from myTable Where myid < 10 order by myid DESC Limit 10
```

get last 5 records of current index

```
Select * from myTable Where myid > 10 order by myid ASC Limit 10
```

But I don't know how to combine these two statements.

Comment: can you upload the table structure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To combine two queries with the same number of columns, use `UNION`:

```
Select * from (Select * from myTable Where myid < 10 order by myid DESC Limit 10)
Union All
Select * from (Select * from myTable Where myid > 10 order by myid ASC Limit 10)
```

(The double-`Select` are necessary because SQLite does not support `Limit` in a direct subquery of an `Union`.)

If you want the overall result to be ordered, just append `Order by mid` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM   myTable 
WHERE  myid BETWEEN currentIndex-5 AND currentIndex+5 AND
       myid <> currentIndex
```

**EDIT:**

I assume that your `mid` column contains data in sequential order like 1,2,3,4,n.

Comment: This works only if the `myid` column contains consecutive values.

Comment: it seems correct when all of records are in table are not deleted yet.

Comment: @Yaqub Ahmad: What heppen if my currentIndex is 3? Will app got crash?